# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mollie\Api\MollieApiClient' not found

Tags: php, api

So, it's my first time using an API for transactions, but I have a difficult time importing the class.

I use the Mollie API and installed it with the composer.

I use mollie 2.0.

This is how my folder structure looks like and where I store my autoloader:

```
htdocs->vendor->autoload.php
```

This is how my main project folder looks like:

```
htdocs->elf->mollieApi.php //(mollieApi is where I try to call the API and do stuff)
```

Inside of the `elf` directory, I have the `mollie-api-php` folder which gets downloaded when you use the composer.

This is how mollieApi.php looks like:

```
// autoload
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

// API key
require "api_keys/apiKey.php";

//Database connection
require("../database/connection.php");

// Use Mollie
use Mollie\Api\MollieApiClient;

$mollie = new MollieApiClient(); //this line doesn't work and throws the fatal error
$mollie->setApiKey(api_key);

//more stuff regarding mollie, but pretty useless to share
```

my `composer.json` looks like this and it is located in my `htdocs`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mollie/mollie-api-php": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

***What I have tried:***

- Move the `mollie-api-php` map into the vendor map
- Moved `autoload.php` into the `elf` directory
- Tried taking out the class which was throwing the error etc and place it in my `elf` directory (which worked, but it then started to complain about having to import other stuff and I could tell the solution would turn into hell, because I also had to import other directories, etc)
- I looked up a couple of StackOverflow questions regarding this, but unfortunately, they're all too specific and the questions do not seem to apply to my problem.

***What I want to achieve:***

I want to be able to import (autoload) the `Mollie` class, get to know what I was doing wrong (`use Mollie\Api\MollieApiClient;`) and actually be able to use it.

Comment: Composer would be putting the mollie-api-php directory into the `vendor/mollie/mollie-api-php/` directory. How did you install it with Composer? Please show your composer.json file.

Comment: I made the edit for you to see.